# CASE END AS result in server error

Tags: mysql

I spent half a day trying to figure this and am still baffled. I am querying a large table. The query executes when I don't have an 'AS' after the Case END.

This does not work and results in server error with code 500

```
SELECT shade,pattern,
CASE 
WHEN colour = 'red' THEN 'hot'
WHEN colour = 'orange' THEN 'hot'
WHEN colour = 'blue' THEN 'cold'
WHEN colour = 'white' THEN 'cold'
ELSE 'UKNOWN'
END AS colourTemp,
texture
FROM tableTest
```

This works

```
SELECT shade,pattern,
CASE 
WHEN colour = 'red' THEN 'hot'
WHEN colour = 'orange' THEN 'hot'
WHEN colour = 'blue' THEN 'cold'
WHEN colour = 'white' THEN 'cold'
ELSE 'UKNOWN'
END,
texture
FROM tableTest
```

my current server has mysql 5.6. I tried the query which does not work on a server with mariaDb and it works with no errors

Comment: Have you tried running the query *directly*?  Like from phpMyAdmin, the mysql console, etc.?

Comment: How are you running this query?  "Server code 500" doesn't mean anything.  Can you check for errors in your code and try to print them out?

Comment: I see this problem when running the query on phpmyadmin. I now tried directly on the server ssh and it works fine. The problem seems to be with phpmyadmin

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.php on line 205

Comment: This was a problem due to phpmyadmin. downgrading my phpmyadmin fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the case value should not be part of the expression):

```
SELECT shade,pattern,
  CASE colour
    WHEN 'red' THEN 'hot'
    WHEN 'orange' THEN 'hot'
    WHEN 'blue' THEN 'cold'
    WHEN 'white' THEN 'cold'
    ELSE 'UKNOWN'
  END AS colourTemp,
texture
FROM tableTest;
```

Comment: Actually both are valid: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case